# Holding value in textarea for Google Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write code that will help some of my users take a JSON response and convert it to a table in Google Sheets. I have the code for the JSON to Table script, courtesy of Amit Agarwal at www.ctrlq.org.

The way that I'm trying to do is that Google Sheets will generate a pop up for my user to copy and paste the JSON straight into it and then it will pass the object to the JSON to Table code.  I'm having a problem figuring out how to actually do that.

Code.gs

```
function showPrompt()
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Upload');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');

}

function setJSON(json)
{
   var json = json; //json object?   
   return json; 
}

// Written by Amit Agarwal www.ctrlq.org

function writeJSONtoSheet(json) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()[1];

  var keys = Object.keys(json).sort();
  var last = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, last).getValues()[0];
  var newCols = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    if (header.indexOf(keys[k]) === -1) {
      newCols.push(keys[k]);
    }
  }

  if (newCols.length > 0) {
    sheet.insertColumnsAfter(last, newCols.length);
    sheet.getRange(1, last + 1, 1, newCols.length).setValues([newCols]);
    header = header.concat(newCols);
  }

  var row = [];

  for (var h = 0; h < header.length; h++) {
    row.push(header[h] in json ? json[header[h]] : "");
  }

  sheet.appendRow(row);

}
```

Dialog box HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
   <script>
   function setJSON() {
   // how do i add value to set to set JSON 
   var json = "" 
   google.script.run.setJSON(json);

   }
</script>

    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  text text 


  <textarea rows="20" cols="20" placeholder="Paste your Data here. Do not format. Do not worry if it looks weird." name="json">DATA</textarea> 

  <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit JSON" onclick="setJSON()">



  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of triggering a dialog via an in-sheet menu and passing the input back to a server side function.

#### Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Input Form Test')
      .addItem('Input Form', 'showInputForm')
      .addToUi();
}

function showInputForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('inputform');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Input Form Test');
}

function logInput(input) {
  Logger.log(input)
}
```

#### inputform.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
    function setJSON(form) {
      var jsonData = document.getElementById('json-data');
      google.script.run.logInput(jsonData.value);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <textarea id="json-data" rows="20" cols="20" placeholder="Paste your data here. Do not format. Do not worry if it looks weird." name="json">DATA</textarea> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit JSON" onclick="setJSON()">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Logging Output

After clicking the "Submit JSON" button with "test input" entered into the form, this is the output in the script logs:

```
[18-06-15 13:47:15:741 PDT] test input
```

#### Notes

- I added an `id` attribute to the `textarea` element
- the `id` is used to fetch the element programmatically
- you may want to perform some client-side validations in `setJSON()`. For example:

  - verify that the value is not still the default value (i.e. `DATA`)
  - validate that the JSON data can be parsed succesfully (i.e. `JSON.parse()`)
  - an example implementation with the above validations:

    ```
    function setJSON(form) {
      var jsonData = document.getElementById('json-data');
      if (jsonData.value == 'DATA') {
        alert("Please enter JSON data into the form.");
          return;
        }
      try {
        JSON.parse(jsonData.value)
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.log(e);  // Outputs to the browser console.
        alert("Unable to parse JSON data.");
        return;
      }
      google.script.run.logInput(jsonData.value);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    ```
- to fit your use case, in `inputform.html` you'd replace the `logInput()` call with either:

  - a function that calls `JSON.parse()` and then calls `writeJSONtoSheet()` with the result
  - `writeJSONtoSheet()` if you update it to expect text and add a `JSON.parse()` call at the beginning of the function

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm kind of new to coding, so apologizes if this is a dumb question:   JSON.parse() is part of the [External APIs] (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) that have been documented? Or is it something custom?

Comment: The [JSON object is a part of Javascript as of the ECMAScript 5.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12). It happens to be useful in the context of data interchange, hence it coming up in the *External APIs* section of the Apps Script documentation.